# Model's method called in RSpec doesn't change objects in test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have this code in spec/models:

```
  describe "update ranking position and player's points" do
    before do
      @player.save
      @player2 = Player.create(firstname: "Second", lastname: "Player", nickname: "second99")
      @match = Match.create(
              { loserscore: 1, winner_player_id: @player.id,
                loser_player_id: @player2.id })
      @player.update_rank
      @player2.update_rank
      Player.update_position
    end

    it { expect(@player.position).to eq 1 }
  end
```

This is the method from model:

```
  def self.update_position
    @players = Player.all
    @players = @players.sort_by { |player| player.rank.to_i }.reverse

    @players.each_with_index do |player, index|
      player.position = index + 1
      player.save
       end
  end
```

When I call this method in controller everything is OK (ranking is updated).

But in RSpec I get `nil`

```
  1) Player update ranking position and player's points should eq 1
     Failure/Error: it { expect(@player.position).to eq 1 }

       expected: 1
            got: nil
```

I tried debug it so I wrote in RSpec:

```
p Player.all.count
```

but it shows

> 2

So for me everything looks OK - there are two rows in `Player` table.
Every others tests passed. I have the problem only with this one method (this is only one class method in this model). App works fine.

Why called method doesn't change `position` column in `Player` table?

Comment: Have you tried throwing an `@player.reload` after `Player.update_position`?

Comment: It works. Thank you. I am a little surprised. Why doesn't it work without `@player.reload`?

Comment: No problem! Rails doesn't know it needs to reload the instance's data (it already loaded the @player model) after you run the class method update_positions so we need to reload the instance so it gets the fresh data from the table. It's one of those "annoying" testing quirks for me (there might be a better answer to this though!)

Answer (score 3):

You need to `reload` the instance variables after performing any updates.

```
it 'should set @player as winner' do
  @player.reload
  expect(@player.position).to eq(1)
end
```